# Selenium finds button but can't click it

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, driver

I am writing a web scraper for the Motley Fool site. The site has a button for `load more articles`. The button is clickable until all the articles are loaded and then disappears. With my code the button is found and is enabled but cannot be clicked. I have used `xpath`, `name`, `css selector` and more/less specific `xpaths` in the hope it becomes clickable but nothing seems to work.

This is my code snippet for this function:

```
url=https://www.fool.com/quote/nasdaq/aep/
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
try:
 while(driver.find element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div[1]/section[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/button').is displayed()):          
      element=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div[1]/section[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[3]/d iv[1]/button')
      driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
      button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div[1]/section[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/button')))
      print(button.text)
      print(button.is_enabled())
      driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", button)
      time.sleep(3)
except:
  pass
```

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you forgot semicolon after click()?
`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", button)`

Comment: can you share the url

Comment: Help us to help you! https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AbhayChaudhary yes the url is: https://www.fool.com/quote/nasdaq/aep/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.fool.com/quote/nasdaq/aep/"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
viewMoreButton = '//span[text()="View More AEP Articles"]'
try:
    while (driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                               viewMoreButton).is_displayed()):
        element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                      viewMoreButton)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
        button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH, viewMoreButton)))
        print(button.text)
        print(button.is_enabled())
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", button)
        time.sleep(3)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried andrey's answer prior to this and it works.